# Link multiple references to the same footnote (HTML)

Tags: html, css, anchor, footnotes

I've got an HTML page that has multiple footnote references that need to go to the same footnote at the bottom of the page. That is, I want <sup>1</sup> and <sup>4</sup> in body content to both link to the same block of text at the bottom.

Most footnote markup is a series of anchor links tied to ids, but by definition they relate one-to-one. Is it possible to do a one-to-many link in HTML somehow?

Comment: A link can't take you to 2 locations on the page, if that's what you're asking. It can only take you one place. But multiple links can take you to the same place in the footer. No issues with that.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your question, and adding what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a many-to-one relationship with anchor links and IDs.

That is, you can only have one instance of each ID, but you can have multiple links pointing to one ID.

```html
<p><a href="#footnote-1">This will go to footnote 1.</a></p>
<p><a href="#footnote-1">This will also go to footnote 1.</a></p>
<p><a href="#footnote-2">This will go to footnote 2.</a></p>

<footer>
  <p id="footnote-1">[1] A footnote.</p>
  <p id="footnote-2">[2] Another footnote.</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

### To the people who came here for a solution for OpenHTMLToPDF:

Got it working by accident:

```html
  Lorem ipsum...
<div class="footnote" id="f-1">This is my first footnote</div><br/>
  Lorem ipsum...
<div class="footnote">Second <strong>footnote</strong>!</div><br/>
  Dolor sit amet...
  <!--This is a reference to the same footnote as the first footnote -->
<a href="#f-1">[1]</a>
```

[Created an issue](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/issues/908) on the github to get a solution or an addition to their wiki.